# Select com Condições de busca

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, algoritmo-de-busca, sql-select

Preciso fazer uma consulta onde exiba somente resultados em uma condição:

```
# Search the Database
$select_sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user LIKE :search OR date_access LIKE :search OR ip LIKE :search AND active LIKE :active ORDER BY id DESC";
$select_db = $connect->prepare($select_sql);
$select_db->bindValue(':search', "%{$search_user}%");
$select_db->bindValue(':active', "yes");
$select_db->execute();
```

Entretanto da maneira acima não funcionou, exibe normalmente os dados conforme a pesquisa mas exibe também os dados que não são do mesmo parâmetro (usuários que não são ativos).

Comment: Joga um parenteses depois do `WHERE` e feche ele antes do `AND`, veja se é o resultado desejado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa especificar a ordem que os critérios serão avaliados utilizando o `()`, como o @rray comentou.

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE (user LIKE :search OR date_access LIKE :search OR ip LIKE :search ) 
AND active LIKE :active ORDER BY id DESC
```

O MySQL trabalha com prioridades entre os operadores lógicos `OR` e `AND` (este último tem prioridade).

A `OR` B `OR` C `AND` D - Primeiro irá resolver "C `AND` D" e depois A `OR` B `OR` "resultado C AND D".

No seu caso, você precisa especificar que primeiro devem ser avaliados os critérios "OR".

**(** A `OR` B `OR` C **)** `AND` D

Comment: era exatamente isso, obrigado galera!